# How to fix conda update conda permission error

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda

```
~$ conda update conda
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/david/anaconda3

  added / updated specs: 
    - conda


The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda: 4.4.10-py36_0 --> 4.4.11-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.4.10-py36_0'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

I was trying to update conda on virtualbox ubuntu 16.04 and this permission error came up. I tried `sudo conda update conda` but it returns `sudo: conda: command not found`. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo -H conda update conda`

Comment: @Paandittya Tried it, didn't recognize the command.  Probably because most installations of Anaconda are not done as root.

Answer (score 35):

I got the same error and solved it by this:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" conda update conda
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this works? Is it a work around needed because of an improper install by the user or a bug with anaconda?

Comment: I thought it wasn't recommended to use sudo with conda

Comment: Your solution saved my day! Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

All conda commands must be run without super user privileges. That's why `sudo conda` command doesn't work.

You may have run conda installation bush file with super user privileges while installing. The user (`david`) running conda doesn't have write permissions to paths(`/home/david/anaconda3`) it needs to modify in the environment, then conda can't do anything. To solve this problem you need to change permissions to paths (`/home/david/anaconda3`).

To change permissions to paths (`/home/user/anaconda3`) using:

```
sudo chown -R user /home/user/anaconda3
```

Comment: In case your conda is not installed there, you can (on *nix) use "which conda" to find out where it is, and then examine/change permissions there.

Comment: Why exactly does this do anything considering the fact that I have already read/write priviledges?

Answer (score 25):

I solved this problem by right clicking on Anaconda Prompt, selecting "Run As Administrator", and typing the command that I want to execute.

This problem arise if at installation time, we select an option install for all user anaconda. It can be solved as I mentioned above - run it as Administrator and type the conda commands for install, updating the packages.

Comment: This helped me, as I was having the same "permission denied" problem in Windows 10. So it's a upvote for me.

Answer (score 12):

It's Permission denied, So just `sudo chown -R frazier:frazier /home/frazier/anaconda3`

PS: change 'frazier' to your user name.

Answer (score 5):

```
conda install numpy
{
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py27_0'.
OSError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

OSError(13, 'Permission denied')}
```

solution:

to change the permission to conda, use the command :

```
sudo chown -R nikhil /home/nikhil/miniconda
```

chown command changes the permission of miniconda to use sudo.
now you have the permisssion to access sudo..
now use:

```
conda update conda
```

- now

  Executing transaction: Done

Answer (score 4):

You have installed Anaconda with sudo or root user. You need to install it with normal `ubuntu/<Your username>` user.
Remove or take backup of the already installed Anaconda (`/home/<user>/anaconda3`).
With normal mode install anaconda ( `bash conda_installer_script` ) .

Check .bashrc for this line and validate it.

```
export PATH="/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

If not add it with proper anaconda path .

Reload .bashrc file and check conda is working by conda list command.

Now you can do `conda update conda`

Comment: Please note that this `export PATH` thing is no longer the way to proceed for `conda>=4.4`. It should be replaced by `source <path_to_conda>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

I too had this error and resolved it by doing the following things - a little strange but worth a try.
1. Run as administrator
2. Run the code below to specifically update package in an environment -myenv
$conda install --name myenv numpy
3. For me the environment was running hence it was not updating, once I closed my running workbooks, and ran Point 1 and 2 .. it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

if you have this error message during package installation in anaconda then follow the given step:

1. open the anaconda prompt by right click.
2. select the run as administrator.
3. type the command for install package.eg conda install `numpy`

Answer (score 1):

Run Anaconda Prompt using "Run as Administrator" option and then
run the command -> `conda update conda`
Then go back to starting Anaconda Prompt as usual and I believe everything should be fine.
Also, don't forget to add Anaconda3 path to Environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to install `conda` after remotely connecting somewhere, you may have this error if you switched to another user after connecting. Eg:

- `ssh remote`, you are logged in as `david`
- `su alfred`
- `bash Anaconda3-linux.sh`
- Installs everything under `/home/alfred`, but tries to access some file in `/home/david`

I have no idea why Anaconda would correctly install under `home/alfred` but for some files it checks in `home/david`, which naturally gives you permission errors. But it does happen if you follow the steps above.

Solution: simply `ssh` directly as `alfred` and then install Anaconda.