# Unable to install anaconda packages using conda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am trying to install keras using conda install -c conda-forge keras
but I always get the following error can someone help?

```
 Executing transaction: failed
    ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(502): An error occurred while uninstalling packag
    e 'defaults::conda-4.5.4-py36_0'.
    PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
    Attempting to roll back.

    Rolling back transaction: done

    PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

Comment: Just check this link, looks like you are having root permissions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181799/conda-update-conda-permission-error

Comment: Are you trying to install it into your root (base) environment? What happens if you try to use a new environment instead?