# Errno 13 Permission denied libssl-1_1-x64.dll when installing various library

Tags: python

I am using miniconda, recently everytime I use conda update or conda install a library, I got a same error:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\test\miniconda3\envs\dash_tf\Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll'
()

not sure why?

For example, I tried to update scikit-learning by doing conda update scikit-learn

```
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::openssl-1.1.1n-h2bbff1b_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\test\\miniconda3\\envs\\dash_tf\\Library\\bin\\libssl-1_1-x64.dll'
()
```

to fix this, I have to use pip install

```
pip install -U scikit-learn  --user
```

any suggestion on this error? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `sudo pip install -U scikit-learn`

Comment: I did, the first time it has an error so I have to add --user

Comment: Would it be possible for you to go to the file and change the permission.

Comment: I checked all permission are allowed for all users and system.

Comment: Windows allow to run cmd `As System Administrator` by mouse right click. Maybe this help. Or maybe Defender blocking file changing operations. Audit and security journal may clarify this problem. Windows is so Windows... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: what do you mean? I am opening up anaconda command windows instead of cmd?

Comment: Then run anaconda as administrator. Or run cmd (command line shell) as Administrator and run anaconda using command line (is it `conda install blah blah` not sure?)

Comment: I just log in anaconda as adminstrator and conda update scikit-learn and I got same error about permission on this file. Thanks for help

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181799/how-to-fix-conda-update-conda-permission-error) is the same solution as I recommended before, but maybe it will help to figure about real problem

Comment: yes rzlvmp, this solution works:   Run Anaconda Prompt using "Run as Administrator" option and then run the command -> conda update conda Then go back to starting Anaconda Prompt as usual and I believe everything should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since you all know that the C drive is the Administrator Drive, no file can be edited or made in it with an automation process. What I'm trying to say is that you can't edit or make new files in the C drive through Python. You can try the `Run file as administrator` option but if that is also not sufficient then you have to change your location.