# Resolve Miniconda Permissions in Ubuntu?

Tags: anaconda, miniconda, ubuntu-22.04

I'm a new `Ubuntu` user (22.04.01) setting up a laptop for development, trying to use `Miniconda`.  To install `Miniconda` I executed the terminal commands from the Quick Command Line Install section of the [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/).

On `Windows` machines after I install `Miniconda` I create new environments, like so:

`conda create -n myenv`

When I try the command in the `Ubuntu` terminal I get an error (report below) and suspect a permissions error because of this line:
`RuntimeError: filesystem error: status: Permission denied [~/conda-bld]`

However, I don't know how to reslove properly. It seems like the installer should have addressed this when it ran rather than have to manually change permissions after the fact.

Can someone advise the best way to resolve this error so I can create environments and perform other conda commands?

Here is the error report:

(base) drew@drew-XPS-15-9570:~$ conda create -n myenv
Channels:

- defaults
  Platform: linux-64
  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): failed

## >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 83, in main_subshell
    exit_code = do_call(args, parser)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 196, in do_call
    result = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/notices/core.py", line 124, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/main_create.py", line 125, in execute
    return install(args, parser, "create")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 360, in install
    unlink_link_transaction = solver.solve_for_transaction(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 148, in solve_for_transaction
    unlink_precs, link_precs = self.solve_for_diff(
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 217, in solve_for_diff
    final_precs = self.solve_final_state(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_libmamba_solver/solver.py", line 207, in solve_final_state
    index = IndexHelper(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/drew/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages/conda_libmamba_solver/index.py", line 126, in __init__
    self._pool = api.Pool()
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: filesystem error: status: Permission denied [~/conda-bld]
```

`$ /home/drew/miniconda3/bin/conda create -n myenv`

environment variables:
CIO_TEST=
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_EXE=/home/drew/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PREFIX=/home/drew/miniconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/drew/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT=/home/drew/miniconda3
CONDA_SHLVL=1
CURL_CA_BUNDLE=
LD_PRELOAD=
PATH=/home/drew/miniconda3/bin:/home/drew/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sb
in:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/
games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=
SSL_CERT_FILE=

```
 active environment : base
active env location : /home/drew/miniconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : /home/drew/.condarc
```

populated config files :
conda version : 24.1.2
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.12.1.final.0
solver : libmamba (default)
virtual packages : __archspec=1=skylake
__conda=24.1.2=0
__glibc=2.35=0
__linux=6.5.0=0
__unix=0=0
base environment : /home/drew/miniconda3  (writable)
conda av data dir : /home/drew/miniconda3/etc/conda
conda av metadata url : None
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
package cache : /home/drew/miniconda3/pkgs
/home/drew/.conda/pkgs
envs directories : /home/drew/miniconda3/envs
/home/drew/.conda/envs
platform : linux-64
user-agent : conda/24.1.2 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.12.1 Linux/6.5.0-26-generic ubuntu/22.04.1 glibc/2.35 solver/libmamba conda-libmamba-solver/23.12.0 libmambapy/1.5.3
UID:GID : 1000:1000
netrc file : None
offline mode : False

An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If you suspect this error is being caused by a malfunctioning plugin,
consider using the --no-plugins option to turn off plugins.

Example: conda --no-plugins install

Alternatively, you can set the CONDA_NO_PLUGINS environment variable on
the command line to run the command without plugins enabled.

Example: CONDA_NO_PLUGINS=true conda install

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers? [y/N]:

Comment: For future seekers, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49597567/3225420).